# Do we need separate config file for every section of web.config file that uses configSource attribute?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-config, configsource

I want to keep some portions of the `web.config` file out of web.config file. So I am using the `configSource` attribute and referring to some other file. When I add more than one configurations in the file other than `web.config`, VS 2010 shows the red wavy line saying `Only one tag allowed at root level`.

Is it required to have separate `.config` file for each config section of web.config file which is using `configSource` attribute? If no, how to get rid of above VS2010 complaint ?

Relevant section from web.config is given below:

```
<MyApplication.Configuration file="Configuration\customAppConfiguration.config" />

<system.diagnostics configSource="Configuration\customAppConfiguration.config" />
```

The `customAppConfiguration.config` file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<MyApplication.Configuration>
  <!-- Contains My Application's configuration -->
</MyApplication.Configuration>
<system.diagnostics>  
  <!-- Diadnostic's configuration -->
</system.diagnostics>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, each of the "externalized" config fragment can **only** contain a single element, so in your case, you need one file for `<MyApplication.Configuration>` and a second physical file for `<system.diagnostics>`.